# Flutter photo_view package gestures not working properly

Tags: flutter, image, gesture, drag

Hi I am a flutter mobile developer and I tried to use this package: https://pub.dev/packages/photo_view/versions for an offline map. I tried zoom and drag and other gestures. It seems working properly for zooming most of the time, but when I tried to drag the picture It has a less than 10 percent success to move it. Here is my code, can somebody help me what coul'd I do wrong? In the package example It seems like It's working properly.

```
class OfflineMapWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final Session session;
  final bool connectedToNetwork;

  const OfflineMapWidget(
      {Key? key, required this.session, required this.connectedToNetwork})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  _OfflineMapWidgetState createState() => _OfflineMapWidgetState();
}

class _OfflineMapWidgetState extends State<OfflineMapWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.black,
      child: SafeArea(
        child: Theme(
          data: ThemeData(
              brightness: Brightness.dark,
              appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
                  backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 65, 116, 131))),
          child: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              leading: MenuWidget(),
              actions: [widget.connectedToNetwork ? QrPaymentButton(session: widget.session) : Container()],
            ),
            body: Container(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              color: Colors.white,
              child: PhotoView(
                imageProvider: AssetImage('assets/images/offline_map.png'),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Update: I found the problem. This Widget was in a ZoomDrawer (another pub dev package), and that Widget confused this one, so I need to find another solution. If somebody else uses this 2 package in one the problem is here. The solution is simple, you can disable drag in ZoomDrawer with the disableDragGesture property. If you don't want to disable it on all menu points you can check if you are in the mentioned menu point and disable only when this one is up.I write this one down in the comments as well so it will be more clear.

Comment: Do not using this lib, it's awful

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. This Widget was in a ZoomDrawer (another pub dev package), and that Widget confused this one, so I need to find another solution. If somebody else uses this 2 package in one the problem is here. The solution is simple, you can disable drag in ZoomDrawer with the disableDragGesture property. If you don't want to disable it on all menu points you can check if you are in the mentioned menu point and disable only when this one is up.